# Arrays, check the smallest, largest, and the average in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, average

Im having some trouble on getting my methods to work, I believe I am doing something wrong in the main method to call the others.  I am not sure if I need an if, while, or for statement. Can anyone help, I really appreciate it. Here is my program...

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int MAX = 100;
    int [] myarray = new int [MAX];
    int fillsize, total = 0, num;
    int smallest = 0, largest = 0;
    fillsize = fillarray (myarray, MAX);
    printarray (myarray, fillsize);

    num = kb.nextInt(); 
    int small = num;
    int large = num;
    total = Average(total, num);
    if(smallest (num, smallest))
    {
      small = num;
    }
    if(largest(num, largest))
    {
       large = num;      
    }
    System.out.println("The smallest value is: " + smallest);
    System.out.println("The largest value is: " + largest);
    System.out.println("The average is: " + total);

    prw.close();
}

public static int fillarray (int[] num, int MYMAX){
    Random gen = new Random();
    int retval = 0;
    int randomnum;
    for(int count = 0; count <= 30; count++){
        randomnum = gen.nextInt(150);
        num [count] = randomnum;
        System.out.println(randomnum);
        retval++;   
    }
    System.out.println("The return value is: " + retval);
    return (retval);
}
public static void printarray (int[] num, int fillsize){
    for (int counts = 0; counts < fillsize; counts++){
        System.out.println("For the position ["+counts+"] the value is " + num[counts]);
    }
    return;
}
public static boolean smallest (int num1, int num2){
    boolean returnValue;
    if (num2 < num1){
        returnValue = true;
    }
    else {
        returnValue = false;
    }
    return (returnValue);
}
public static boolean largest (int number1, int number2){
    boolean returnVal;
    if (number1 > number2){
        returnVal = true;
    }
    else{
        returnVal = false;
    }
    return (returnVal);
}
public static int Average (int avg, int sum){
    int retVal;
    retVal = avg + sum;
    return(retVal);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is you set smallest and largest both to num which makes your if redundant.

Try setting them both to 0.

Also you have variables and methods with the same name which isn't recommended. (confusing).